# On adding a jar using mvn install: install-file: On project standalone-pom: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid

Tags: maven, jar, spark-structured-streaming, apache-bahir

I want to push the bahir jar to my local m2 repository.
I'm using maven-3.5.0 downloaded tar.gz and jdk8, both are set as environment variables and are working fine.

I built apache bahir for spark from the available download from git using maven, which was BUILD SUCCESS and it created a target folder which has the jar called **bahir-parent_2.11-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar**

now when I execute:

```
$mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/awisha/trial/bahir-master/target/bahir-parent_2.11-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.bahir -DartifactId=spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11 -Dversion=2.2.0
```

Its supposed to push the jar to my local .m2/repository. But instead it gives me the following error:

```
[ERROR]   Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR]   [0]  'packaging' is missing.
```

But when I used "apt install maven" : maven-3.3.9, I got BUILD SUCCESS
I'm not able to figure out why is it giving me error when using maven-3.5.0.

Comment: You do not need to use the install-file goal to do this. Just `mvn install` will do it for you. In fact the most common maven command line is `mvn clean install`, which will clean out the target directory, perform a new build, and then install the resulting artifact into your local repository

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply add "-Dpackaging=jar" to your mvn install:install-file cmd:

> $mvn install:install-file **-Dpackage=jar**
>   -Dfile=/home/awisha/trial/bahir-master/target/bahir-parent_2.11-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
>   -DgroupId=org.apache.bahir -DartifactId=spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11 -Dversion=2.2.0